# DOMContentLoaded In Fire Fox

Tags: performance, firefox, dom

Hopefully a simple question to answer, does anyone know where the DOMContentLoaded metric can be found in Fire Fox. I can find it easily in Chrome (in blue at the bottom) and IE (Network > click website > Timings tab). Do I need a separate extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while using the Fire Fox extension, Firebug. Open the Net (Network) tab, click Html to filter down to your page (optional), look at the Timeline section (column on the right) and hover over the ms. At the bottom of that tooltip, you'll see the DomContentLoaded metric.